# Lightbox with new created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have a lightbox-plugin (`fancyboy`) which I am running on my site.
For almost every image, this lib is working as excepted.

However, there is a snippet in my code (from a 3rd-party library) which creates an image-gallery (`adgallery`) - taken from the TER (Typo3 Repository)

```
    var context = this;
    var image = this.images[index];
    var img_container = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('ad-image');
    var img = $(new Image()).attr('src', image.image);
    if(image.link) {
      var link = $('<a href="'+ image.link +'" class="lightbox"></a>');
      link.append(img);
      img_container.append(link);

    } else {
      img_container.append(img);
    }
```

As you can see, i already added the "class="lightbox" attribute to the link. The dom looks good:

```
<a href="/uploads/tx_adgallery/apfel-prasi43.jpg" class="lightbox">
    <img src="/typo3temp/_processed_/csm_apfel-prasi43_d89a571bb8.jpg" width="400" height="300">
</a>
```

However, the lightbox-event isn't triggered. Instead, it just opens the link in the same tab.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('.ad-gallery').adGallery({
                width:'###WIDTH###',
                height:'###HEIGHT###',
                effect:'####',
                slideshow:{
                    enable:true,
                    autostart:true,
                    speed:3000,
                    start_label:'Lecture',
                    stop_label:'Pause'
                }
            });
     });
</script>
```

Same as above, the HTML-Dom is correct. I already tried to use `$(window).load()`, but that didn't do the trick.

When I add the lightbox-class to the thumbnails however, it is working.
Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add a link for an example? Sometimes it is being happened, that the error is somewhere else.

Comment: @reporter i added a link in the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue hide is dynamic content (big image is re-rendered on every change, so all events are missed).
You may try this trick:

```
$('.ad-gallery').on('mousedown touchstart', '.ad-image a', function(){
    $(this).fancybox();
});
```

This will activate/reactivate fancybox function on every `mousedown` and `touchstart` that happens just before user clicks.